# How to stop nodejs from killing a child process on out of memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management

I am working in Node.Js and with large files. I am invoking a child process of python script to work on these large files. Now problem is, on large files the memory runs out and node js abort the process by killing it. I know about --max-old-space-size but I don't just want to limit the size. I want node.js to keep working on the process if it runs out of memory. F

For example, Node.js performs a process with 2GB ram allowed in 1 minute. I limit the memory size to 1GB ram, it should run the process in 2 minutes but not give an error. It should use a queue or something else.

EDIT:
This is the command I am executing from child process using spawn.

```
let extExecCommand = "cat file.json | python sample-script.py > output-file"
let extensionScript = childProcess.spawn(extExecCommand, {shell: true});
```

When the size of file.json is very large, the node aborts the process and kills the child process. I don't want that to happen. I want node js to keep executing the process and maintain some type of data structure.

Comment: You do not show what you're actually trying to do or any of your code (which makes it hard to know how to help), but typically you would look to process your file in smaller pieces either as a stream or in lines or in some sort of chunk so that you never have to have the entire file in memory at once, only a small piece of it.  Questions here will nearly always get better and faster answers if you show your actual code so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> I want node.js to keep working on the process if it runs out of memory?*

Guess it's not possible to avoid the Heap-Out-of-Memory error.

You could use two things.

First, [delegate a separate process to PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) with `-max-memory-restart` option and run it via ecosystem file, like: `pm2 start test.yaml`

```
apps:
  - script: ./index.js
    name: 'PYTHON'
    instances: 1
    out_file: "/dev/null"
    autorestart: true
    max_memory_restart: '100M'
    log_date_format: 'DD/MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

The second option is using various queue job managers, like Bree, Bull, Agenda and put there your resourceful tasks, split jobs in parts (if it's possible) and then manage it. Node.js does it via `worker_thread`.

But I guess, something is wrong with your project architecture, and should not store such amount of data `in-memory`. You could access large files or data via [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), from the database or other storage.